# How can I filter a keyword in logstash message field in new field

Tags: filter, logstash, message

Can I filter key word in message field? For example, this is log: " session opened for user root by (uid=0)"--> And I want create a new field to keep data like "root", I wanna filter user name when someone login to. Do you have any idea or plugin to solve my problems?
Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: It can be easily solved by means of Grok pattern matching. That is its purpose, check the official documentation and ask something more precisely if you have an error or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`grok` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to extract the user's name and id like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "session opened for user %{USERNAME:user_name} by \(uid=%{NONNEGINT:user_id}\)" }
  }
}
```